# Datagrab - Importing more than one Grid row data for each row in CSV

Tags: datagrab, csv

I have this problem with importing data from CSV

Suppose I have CSV that contains a list people. Suppose these people have multiple phone numbers.

Given these assumptions, let us try this example

Suppose there is a person named John Doe who has 2 phone numbers - one for mobile, the other is for landline

In the CSV, it would be represented as

```
FirstName   LastName    PhoneNumber     PhoneNumberType
...
John        Doe         12345798        mobile
John        Doe         987654321       landline
...
```

Now here is the question. How does Datagrab know that those 2 rows are the same person with 2 different numbers?

Is there a way for Datagrab to import these 2 numbers into Grid for that 1 person?

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine that a CSV is not the best way to represent this data, and that it'll prevent you from successfully importing into a Grid field.

I would take the CSV data and (using PHP or some other tool) reformat it into XML, which will much more readily represent the nested sets of fields in a Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this to work out for you, if so what did you use to import several grid field-data into the entry?

Best regards 
Dave

Comment: Please delete this answer and make a comment on the original question.